# vscode es6 debug cant work normal

Tags: debugging, ecmascript-6, visual-studio-code

I use vscode to learn es6.

```
├─.vscode
│  └─lauhch.json
├─index.js
└─jsconfig.json
```

when i use `let`,it works well

```
if (1) {let b = 2;console.log(b);}
console.log(typeof b);
```

> DEBUG CONSOLE

```
2
undefined
```

but when i use `...` or `var [foo, boo, baz] = [1, 2, 3];`,error

> DEBUG CONSOLE

```
var [foo, boo, baz] = [1, 2, 3];
    ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

Why this happens and how to solve it?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: so,how to solve it ?and why?Thanks anymore.

Comment: What do you expect `var [foo, boo, baz] = [1,2,3]` to do?

Comment: I just start to learn , I copy this form the page,https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-rest-parameters-and-defaults/ and https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/05/es6-in-depth-destructuring/ .it seems that part of es6 can't work in my code

Answer (score 0):

I try to run this in node cli,it didn't work,too. It must be error env.

Comment: it can works in node cli by `node --harmony`,so, just edit    `launch.json`like this
`        "runtimeArgs": [
            "--nolazy",
            "--harmony"
        ],
`

Answer (score 0):

Check what version of NodeJS you are using. I'm running 6.9.1 and your code (destructuring) is working fine. I'm getting

> foo == 1, boo == 2, and baz == 3

Remember NodeJS is using Google's V8 JavaScript Engine, and if that feature is not in V8, then it will not be in NodeJS. You can check what features are implemented in NodeJS at [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) website.